# How to manipulate 64 bits?

Tags: c++, bitmask

I am trying to manipulate 64 bits. I use the number to store in an unsigned long long int.To test the porcess I ran the following program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 unsigned long long x = 1;
 int cnt = 0;
 for(int i =0 ;i<64;++i)
 {
    if((1<<i)&x)
    ++cnt;
 }
 cout<<cnt;
 }
```

but the output of the cnt is 2 which is clearly wrong. How Do I manipulate 64 bits? where is the correction?  Actually I am trying to find parity, that is number of 1's in binary representation of a number less than 2^63.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For it's 64-bit, you should use a 64-bit 1. So, try this:

```
if(((unsigned long long) 1<<i)&x)
```

Comment: Even better: Use a cast to `uint64_t`, which is actually guaranteed to be precisely 64 bits. `unsigned long long` may be anything larger than 8 bits, including 16 or 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

`(1<<i)` will overflow when `i` greater than 32

you can write the condition like `(x >> i) & 1`

Answer (score 0):

What is meant by manipulation in your case? I am thinking you are going to test each and every bit of variable x. Your x should contain maximum value because you are going to test every bit of your variable x

```
int main()
{
 unsigned long long x = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
 int cnt = 0;
 for(int i =0 ;i<64;++i)
 {
    if((1<<i)&x)
    ++cnt;
 }
 cout<<cnt;
 }
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to find parity, that is number of 1's in binary representation of a number less than 2^63.